# How can I visually see changes made to a scene since the last git commit

Tags: unity, scene-graph, scene, version-control

I'd like to see the changes made in a scene (.unity file) before I commit them to git.

I have looked into several GIT/Unity solutions but all of them are made for merging changes and not for showing a diff with last version.

The problem with scene files is that they use GUIDs that point to other assets and when I open a diff for a scene file I can't really make anything out of it.

**For example:**
[image: git diff]

**Instead, I'd like to see something like this:**
[image: visual diff]

**Is there anything existing that does this?**

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to see the changes made in a scene (.unity file) before I
> commit them to git.

Any decent git tool will do this *provided the scene file is not binary*; but, as you mentioned, the GUID references makes it difficult to read. If the scene is binary, serialization may be updated in `Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Asset Serialization`; but, **be warned: data-loss may occur** (See [Draco18s comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/141918#comment-256114) below.).

> I have looked into several GIT/Unity solutions but all of them are made for merging changes and not for showing a diff with last version.

Seeing the changes made to a single file is one of the core features of git log. In fact, there's a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176601/git-diff-file-against-its-last-change) on that. Basically you'd use something like

```
git log --follow path/to/scene.unity
```

to display the history of that file. Add `-1` to display the most recent changes to the specified file. Ommit `-1` and use `-p` to see the patch made for each commit that modified that file. I recommend reading through the stackoverflow question before touching the [git-log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) because it's *very long*.

> Instead, I'd like to see something like this:
>
> [scene graph diff]
>
> Is there anything existing that does this?

As far as I can tell, **No**. That being said, [Unity for Git](https://unity.github.com/) appears to be the natural place to find it. Since it's in alpha, you should create an issue there to address this. Since it's unique to applying git diff on unity's intrinsic scene graphs, I suspect it'l be strongly relevant there.

Comment: *`Any decent git tool will do this`* ...provided the file isn't *binary.* Which *can* be set (Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Asset Serialization). I've got two projects right now, one where the scene file is binary data and one where it's text. The text one was changed because of an asset I imported that encouraged changing to "Force Text" because of some aspect of the plugin/asset/target platform performed better. WARNING: changing modes *can* result in data loss.

Answer (score 1):

This git-for-unity tool might be something you could use. Not a directed graph but more visual than just a git text log https://flashg.github.io/GitMerge-for-Unity/

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend you to just use Git with Bitbucket (as push origin !) as it provides a really nice GUI that lets you see graphical representation of your branch and commit history as well as changes within the text files where You can even see changes in the code in red and green plus many other nice workflow features.

Comment: I thing you totally misunderstood my question. I'm talking about text based scene files that contain guid references to other unity objects. Unless there's some kind of smart bitbucket client which I'm not aware of, that can resolve those references - you're totally off base here.